# Failed when running powershell code in azure automation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, runbook

I set an **azure policy** adding two tags, which are `CreatedTime` and `Type`.
The value of `CreatedTime` is `utcNow()`, which default format is `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ'.`

My goal is to delete all resources whose **Type** is `private` and **created time** is longer than **2 days** by running **powershell** code in **azure automation**.

I have done it in power shell **locally**, but when I run the code in **automation**, it failed. I will post the code and the error page below.

**Anybody can tell me what's wrong with my code? Or I miss something?**

This is my code in Azure Automation:

```
   $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint 
$servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

    $AllRes = (get-AzureRMResource).ResourceId
    $TimeOutDays=2
    foreach ($Res in $AllRes){
    $Resource = Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $Res
    $Tags=$Resource.Tags
    $TypeInTags=$Tags['Type']
    $CreatedTimeInTags=$Tags['CreatedTime']
try{
    $CreatedTime=[Datetime]::ParseExact($CreatedTimeInTags, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null)
}
catch{
    $CreatedTime=[Datetime]::ParseExact($CreatedTimeInTags, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ', $null)
}
finally
{
    $CreatedTime
}
    $daypan=((get-date)-$CreatedTime).Days
    if($TypeInTags -eq 'private')
    {
    if($daypan -gt $TimeOutDays)
        {
            $daypan
            Remove-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $Res -Force
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error page:
Suspended

```
The runbook job was attempted 3 times, but it failed each time.  Common reasons that runbook jobs fail can be found here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-troubleshooting-automation-errors
```

[image]

A piece of error message:

```
Get-AzureRMResource : ResourceNotFound : The Resource 
'microsoft.alertsmanagement/smartDetectorAlertRules/Failure+Anomalies+-+arrowbottest2-config' under resource group 
'arrowbot2' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
At line:28 char:17
+     $Resource = Get-AzureRMResource -ResourceId $Res
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
ResourceNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.GetAzureResourceCmdlet
 
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:34 char:5
+     $CreatedTime=[Datetime]::ParseExact($Tags['CreatedTime'], 'yyyy-M ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
 
Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:35 char:5
+     $daypan=((get-date)-$CreatedTime).Days
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
 

Cannot find an overload for "op_Subtraction" and the argument count: "2".
At line:35 char:5
+     $daypan=((get-date)-$CreatedTime).Days
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
 
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:34 char:5
+     $CreatedTime=[Datetime]::ParseExact($Tags['CreatedTime'], 'yyyy-M ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
```

**For the type of `$Tags['CreatedTime']`**, I did this for a test: `$Tags['CreatedTime'].GetType().FullName`.

[image]

Comment: can you post the output of `$CreatedTimeInTags`

Comment: Do you mean the output of  `$CreatedTimeInTags` in automation?

Comment: Yes. It looks like the parsing of the date fails so can you just post the output of variable?

Comment: Maybe everything works if you just replace the line where you parse the date with this: `[datetime]$CreatedTime = $Tags['CreatedTime']`

Comment: OK, I am rerunning this code, and it would take some times, wait a minute please.

Comment: Bad Luck, it didn't work. @MartinBrandl

Comment: Sorry, the error message is too much to post them all, I took a piece of it.@DanielBjörk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong.

**1.Didn't specify the resource I need.**

**Detailes:**

That's the reason for the error message: `Can not index to a null array.`  I traverse the entire resource in my subscription, but the
resources created before I set the policy do not have a Tag named
`"CreatedTime"` or `"Type"`, so when I run `$Tags=$Resource.Tags`, it
said `Can not index to a null array.`

**My solution:**

Do `$AllRes = (get-AzResource -TagName "CreatedTime").ResourceId` other than  `$AllRes = (get-AzureRMResource).ResourceId`.
I found that AzureRM module don't
recognize  `-TagName` as a variable, so I import the Az module and
change every AzureRM module to Az module.

**2.Confused with utcNow().**

**Details:**

As I said, with utcNow() function I get a DateTime object with default
format `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ'`, after testing a lot,
I found some special resources like application insight' tag value is
not formated with `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ'`, and when I call
it, it comes to a string.

**My solution:**

So when I use it comparing to `get-date`, I
need to do two things:

(1)Change the string to DateTime object;

(2)Use try-catch to meet two kinds of formats.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say The value of CreatedTime is `utcNow()`, then that value is already a DateTime object and you should not treat it as string. (you *think* it is a string, because when you write it out to console, it will show its `ToString()` representation)

Simply do

```
$CreatedTime=$Tags['CreatedTime']
```

You can test this with a write-host `$Tags['CreatedTime'].GetType().FullName`

Comment: @DorisLv So, what does `Write-Host $Tags['CreatedTime'].GetType().FullName` reveal?. (Please do not comment things like _does not work_ everytime. Explain what happens and add the FULL exception in the question as formatted text.)

Comment: I have updated my code in my question. I tried your suggestion before, and the same error shows up. Even though I set the tag' value utcNow(), it comes to a string other than a DateTime object when I do this: `$CreatedTimeInTags=$Tags['CreatedTime']` .

Comment: @DorisLv Please show us what you get when doing `Write-Host $Tags['CreatedTime'].GetType().FullName`. I still believe it is **NOT** as string, but a DateTime object. You are just not checking the Type and therefore seeing only the string representation of the date.

Comment: I update a picture in my question body, you can see that clearly. @Theo